# Magento simple module

Tags: magento2, module, router

i have an new module at app/code/MyVendor/MyModule and i try to understand structure of module magento2. I have some task of trainning list.I have an controller with execute() method echo sometext to with the new route i define in /etc/routes.xml. Can I have some solution to display these text to the some another page like Home, Category, Checkout and Cart ?.Help me!

Comment: Take a look at this https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/view-block-layout-template-magento-2.html

Comment: tks, i have look at speedly and maye exactly all thing i am finding.Tks!

Comment: Again i see you in there.Good a nice day.